# Getting a particular value from a string using regular expression

Tags: regex, tcl

In tcl language, I get some output as:

```
xCommand Experimental Conference ParticipantList Search CallId: 231

OK
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 1 Index: 0
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 1 ParticipantId: "sip:9503806@10.89.70.92;ci=23543253"
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 1 Uri: "sip:9503806@10.89.70.92;ci=23543253"
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 1 DisplayName: "9503806"
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 1 Status: "connected"
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 1 AudioMute: Off
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 2 Index: 1
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 2 ParticipantId: "sip:9503808@10.89.70.92;ci=23543256"
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 2 Uri: "sip:9503808@10.89.70.92;ci=23543256"
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 2 DisplayName: "9503808"
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 2 Status: "connected"
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 2 AudioMute: Off
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 3 Index: 2
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 3 ParticipantId: "sip:9503807@10.89.70.92;ci=23543254"
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 3 Uri: "sip:9503807@10.89.70.92;ci=23543254"
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 3 DisplayName: "9503807"
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 3 Status: "connected"
*r ParticipantListSearchResult Participant 3 AudioMute: Off
** end
```

I need:

```
DisplayName: "9503806"
DisplayName: "9503808"
DisplayName: "9503807"
```

as my output, how to write the regular expression for it?

Answer (score 1):

You just need 1 wild card to match the varying numbers and the right function. Let's say your text is in the variable `$output`, then do:

```
set results [regexp -all -inline -- {DisplayName: "[0-9]+"} $output]
```

`$results` is a list. So if you want to print them one below the other, you can do:

```
puts [join $results \n]
```

[codepad demo](http://codepad.org/nt5Xgmxi)

Answer (score 0):

How about `DisplayName: "[0-9]*"`